# An alternative to iis/asp.net/asp while still being able to code in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Is there any alternative to `IIS`/`ASP.Net`/`ASP` while still being able to code in `C#` (for web back end development)  ? Is there any light weight open source alternative to `IIS`,`ASP.Net` combo ?

Comment: It would help us to know why..

Comment: @CResults: I currently develop in C++/C# (desktop development) and now learning web development. Since most of my web projects are very small, I'm just searching for a simple/light weight server which will forward me the request and let me handle responses on my own in a more transparent way. Sorry - if that still sounds vague :).

Comment: You may be best sticking with IIS/ASP.Net then and looking at MVC - it comes without all the overhead/weight of WebForms and is much closer to the 'request/response' goal that you are after.

Answer (score 1):

Mono is the open source alternative [Mono project](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the new IIS Express? It provides you with a configurable IIS 7.5 style platform per website solution. It's really useful when developing on XP for instance where previously you would have been limited to 1 website per development machine.

It's now available as part of the Visual Studio 2010 SP 1 download.

Check it out here;

[IIS Express Overview](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/868/iis-express-overview/)

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm a bit unclear as to your actual project requirements there is nothing stopping you from creating a C# based application and then exposing a web service which your application could connect to written in any web based language of your choice. However you will still have to host the web service in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cassini:
http://ultidev.com/products/Cassini/index.htm

Cassini is very reliable but not designed for heavy usage which is why UltiDev have built UWS Ultidev Web Server Pro based on the original Cassini Server:
http://ultidev.com/products/UWS/

Comment: Why do you state it's being replaced by UltiDev?  In some shops I suppose that is true, but that isn't the case for everyone. As Brian Scott pointed out, IIS Express is Microsoft's solution for something a bit more powerful than Cassini.

Comment: @Pedro See the quote from the developers website:
<quote>
Good old Cassini is getting obsolete. Replace it with the new and advanced UltiDev Web Server Pro, which is also free and redistributable. 
</quote>
See as follows: http://ultidev.com/products/cassini/

Comment: They are recommending you use their product instead of Microsoft's.  They aren't saying that their product will be an official replacement.

Comment: How does this make my suggestion of UltiDev's product incorrect? I believe it correctly answers the question. If it's your opinion that Cassini is not becoming obsolete or outdated, try finding the developers recent updates or even their support page for the product. Difficult?? Why is this? They used to list it on the WebMatrix portal/site, now the only mention IIS7. Not becoming obsolete? That's your opinion.

Comment: One thing that might be causing confusion is I suspect you are referring to UltiDev's version of Cassini as being obsolete, which is not the same thing as MS Cassini (which ships with VisualStudio.)